# I'm confused about The Matrix Representation of Linear Operators Formula when the basis is not the standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

[My Question/Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1dhh.jpg)

I read that a Linear Operator in Quantum Mechanics can be represented as
A = $\sum_{ij} A_{ij}|u_{i}\rangle \langle u_{j}|$.

If A =
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2\\
4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$, I used the formula above and got that
A =
$$\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 2\\
0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$$.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, since the basis I used is {[1/$\sqrt{2}$, 1/$\sqrt{2}$], [1/$\sqrt{2}$, -1/$\sqrt{2}$]}. What am I doing wrong? I also showed my work in the image attached.

Comment: That assumes that the $A_{ij}$ are the matrix representation in the basis $| u_i \rangle$.

Comment: In general, $A = \sum_{ij} \langle u_i|A|u_j\rangle |u_i\rangle\langle u_j |$ for an orthonormal basis $\{|u_i\rangle\}$. If $A_{ij}$ are the entries of the representation of $A$ relative to this basis (so that $A_{ij} = \langle u_i|A|u_j\rangle$) or more specifically if $A$ is a matrix and $\{|u_i\rangle\}$ denotes the standard basis, then this becomes $A = \sum_{ij} A_{ij} |u_i\rangle\langle u_j |$